Trying to change a value from inside a function but it doesn't change when I exit the function
Trying to make a barebones Pokemon game and switching wont work
When trying to switch Pokemon I can get the code to recognize activePlayerMon= has had a value switch when running through the switchOption() function but once the debugger leaves the function it reverts back to the originally given value when you are first prompted to choose a Mon
def fight(playerlist, computerlist):
    print('\n',playerlist[1].name,'\n',playerlist[2].name,'\n',playerlist[3].name,'\n')
    initFight = int(input('Choose your starting Pokemon\n'))
    playerlist[int(initFight)].fightPrompt(computerlist[1])

    activePlayerMon = playerlist[initFight]
    activeComputerMon = computerlist[1]
    
    def switchOption(determine_user):
        global activePlayerMon, activeComputerMon
        if determine_user == 1:
            print('\n',playerlist[1].name,'\n',playerlist[2].name,'\n',playerlist[3].name,'\n')
            changeMon = int(input('Choose who you\'d like to switch to'))
            activePlayerMon = playerlist[changeMon]
        elif determine_user == 0:
            changeMon = randint(1,3)
            activeComputerMon = computerlist[changeMon]


    while playerlist[1].HP != 0 and playerlist[2].HP != 0 and playerlist[3].HP != 0 or computerlist[1].HP != 0 and computerlist[2].HP != 0 and computerlist[3].HP != 0:
        print('\n',activePlayerMon.name,'- \n',activePlayerMon.HP,'\ ',activePlayerMon.MHP,'\n',activeComputerMon.name,'- \n',activeComputerMon.HP,'\ ',activeComputerMon.MHP,'\n')
        fightOption = int(input('Would you like to-\n  1. Fight\n  2. Heal\n  3. Switch\n'))
        if fightOption == 1:
                << attacking function call >>
        elif fightOption == 2:
                << healing function call >>  

        elif fightOption == 3:
            switchOption(1)

I tried a variation where the switchOption() function is outside the fight() function using arguments for the playerList[] and activePlayerMon= but it did the same thing.
I also had a version that was just hardcoded to work for only the player but pivoted to the strategy to make it easier to code for the computer
I understand that a lot of the code is unoptimized, but I'm genuinely stuck on just making this work in a modular way.
In short, How do I make it so that when activePlayerMon's value is switched inside the switchOption() function, it keeps the change and doesn't just revert back to the old value?
I'm willing to upload the files to GitHub if need be

activePlayerMon is global inside of switchOption, but it is not inside of fight.  Try printing activePlayerMon at the start of switchOption to see.

switchOption() would need to use nonlocal instead of global declarations, in order to access the local variables in fight().

TL;DR
Use nonlocal instead of global.

Python variable system use scopes, that means that variables have a certain domain where they're accessible, and there can be another variable with the same name but another value in another scope. The global scope contains the variables defined directly at the root of the script, not within any function, class or other thing.
When using global activePlayerMon, activeComputerMon, you tell Python to search the variables in the global scope. However, your variables aren't defined in the global scope (because scopes don't inherit), but in the scope of a parent function. To access these variables, you need to use nonlocal activePlayerMon, activeComputerMon at the start of the function where you want to access them.
Here's the new code of the function:
    def switchOption(determine_user):
        nonlocal activePlayerMon, activeComputerMon
        if determine_user == 1:
            print('\n',playerlist[1].name,'\n',playerlist[2].name,'\n',playerlist[3].name,'\n')
            changeMon = int(input('Choose who you\'d like to switch to'))
            activePlayerMon = playerlist[changeMon]
        elif determine_user == 0:
            changeMon = randint(1,3)
            activeComputerMon = computerlist[changeMon]

